# Series converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is this series converge ?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^{n}}$$

My class disscussed this problem in some hours . Finally , my teacher used  a lemma which isn't basic ( i.e : a result in a research paper ) . I hope someone can give me a more simpler proof .

Comment: It depends on how close $n$ gets to an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, and that's not such a simple question.

Comment: And using that lemma, what is the conclussion? Does the series diverge or converge?

Comment: The lemma involves an inequality of approximation of $\pi$ .  The series is converge

Comment: Using estimates for the irrationality measure of $\pi$, it's possible to show $|\tan n|=O(n^\alpha)$ for all natural $n$, sufficient for convergence. As far as I know, there is no easier way.

Comment: Link/description of said lemma/research paper would be nice.

Comment: Hm... seems fairly related to this series:$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{u^k+v^k}$$due to Euler's formula.

Comment: By the technique of the *hopeful criterion* it converges to $0.0468$ approximately. When $\tan n $ becomes large $2^n$ is far much larger. This is what I saw experimentally.